# Can't connect to router after adding Google DNS

Tags: router, dns

I configured my router's DNS to use the two Google DNS IPs, which sped up web surfing *a lot*.  However, I can now no longer connect to my router at 192.168.1.1.

What is the reason for this? Do I have to reset the router and add the DNS in the OS instead?

Comment: DNS has no effect on requests made by IP address.  What actually happens when you try to connect to your router via the above IP address?  Can you ping it at that address?

Answer (score 2):

If changing the DNS servers were the only change you made, this should have no affect what so ever on accessing your server via IP address.

I recommend you attempt to restart your router, and failing that, perhaps a restore as something else must have gone wrong.

I would also advise you double check the address of the router.

Just to double check - whilst you say the router is at 192.168.1.1 - are you accessing it via that (http://192.168.1.1) or are you just saying that is the router and are you attempting to access it via a name (such as http://router) - if you are doing anything other than the IP, try via the ip!

Comment: Rebooting the router solves the problem.  I should have tried that first.  Thanks!