# DNS error when connecting to router via IP

Tags: google-chrome, router, dns

Today, I tried to connect to my router using it's IP (192.168.x.x) and I got a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on Google Chrome / Windows 10. I do use Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4), but the issue did not just start directly after changing it, I could connect to my router via IP, while this DNS server was selected.

Before you jump into "this has already been asked", I have tried the following:

- Flushing DNS cache on Chrome **did not** help
- Flushing DNS via "ipconfig /flushdns" **did not** help
- Restarting both the computer and router **did not** help
- Weirdly, changing DNS server to be chosen automatically **did** help to connect to the router via IP

A similar question has been asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/331159/cant-connect-to-router-after-adding-google-dns), however, the solution there did not help me. Additionally, I do not recall changing anything in my network settings or set-up. Does anyone have any additional suggestions what the issue could be? I could try a different browser, however, to me that is not a solution.

Comment: [Why can't Chrome load a web page? ERR\_NAME\_NOT\_RESOLVED](http://superuser.com/q/719559)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the comment, but as I have stated, I have tried deleting the cache in Chrome. The other answer suggested did also not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer, even though it is highly trivial, but I could not find it as an answer anywhere else.

I simply waited for a day and the problem randomly disappeared. A comment on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved) question suggested something similar, however:

> I've seen the same problem, and this is not an issue with the data in the DNS system. I tried two different servers with dig, host and ping, all of which gave correct information, yet Chromium on my Ubuntu box couldn't find the record. (Chrome on Windows and on an Android tablet worked fine at the same time.) Clearing Chrome's DNS cache did not help. The problem went away after a couple of hours.

I have tried every single solution on this question and *quite a few more*, but nothing helped. Then after waiting for a day, the problem has gone away. So my suggestion for those that cannot find anything else working: wait and be patient. If it's urgent that you connect to your router, it helped me to remove Google's DNS server even though I accessed it via IP.